# Condition number of a polynomial root problem

Tags: numerical-methods, condition-number

I dont't understand how the condition number is defined for a problem such as:

$x^2-2xp+1=0,\ p\geq1$ Here there are two roots $x_-=p-\sqrt{p^2-1}$ and $x_+=p+\sqrt{p^2-1}$

I understand that the sum is not well conditionned because the relative error can become very high if the numbers sum up to something close to zero, so when $p$ is close to $1$ both roots $x_-$ and $x_+$ are unstable and when $p$ is big $x_-$ is unstable (that is why we take advantage of the fact that $x_-=\frac{1}{x_+}$ and the division is a stable operation).

But I don't understand why the condition number $K(p)\simeq \frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2-1}}$ for $p>1$

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how I should understand the condition number.

Comment: That “trick” when $p$ is large is only to avoid numerical cancellation. It has nothing to do with the sensitivity of the root.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Ok but do can you explain $K(p)\simeq\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2-1}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the (relative) condition number of $x_+(p)$ is
$$
K(p)=\frac{p}{x_+}\frac{dx_+}{dp}
=
\frac{p}{p+\sqrt{p^2-1}}
\left(
1+\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2-1}}
\right)
=
\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2-1}}.
$$
The root $x_+$ is sensitive for $p$ close to one with $K$ growing to infinity and insensitive for large $p$ with $K\approx 1$.